# What is the closed form of the sequence : $ a_{n+2} = 2a_{n+1}-a_n+2^n+2 $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, closed-form, telescopic-series

> I would like to find the closed form  of the sequence given by 
>   $$ a_{n+2} = 2a_{n+1}-a_n+2^n+2,~~~~n > 0~~~~and~~~a_1 = 1, ~~~~a_2 = 4$$

This task is in the topic of differential and difference equation.
I don't know how to start solving this problem and what are we looking for? ($a_n, a_{n+2}$)

I do know how to solve the following form
$$ a_{n+2} = 2a_{n+1}-a_n $$ using linear algebra as well. The actual problem I encountered  the obstructionist term $\color{red}{2^n+2}$.

> Are there some kind of **variational constant** method for recursive linear sequences,?

I only now this method for linear ODE with constant coefficient.

But I believe that such method could be doable here as well. Can any one provide me with a  helpful hint or answer?.

Comment: If you really are just looking for somewhere to start, this is a classic example of a problem that can be solved with generating functions.

Comment: @PatrickStevens why do you want him to use such complicated vocabulary?

Comment: @GuyFsone I… don't. They asked "how to start solving this problem", and I answered.

Comment: What you want to do is to `solve a non-homogeneous recurrence relation`.  If you type this in the MSE search box you will get 65 hits.

Comment: I don't see why this post is still on hold>>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> **Answer:**  By telescoping twice we obtain the following formula $$\color{red}{a_n =  2^{n}+ n(n-2)}$$

Enforcing  $X_n=a_{n+1}-a_n$ yields that 
$$a_{n+2} = 2a_{n+1}-a_n+2^n+2\implies (a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}) - (a_{n+1}-a_n)= 2^n+2$$
this leads to 
$$\color{blue}{X_{n+1} - X_n= 2^n+2}$$

By telescopic sum we have
$$X_{n+1} -X_1 = \sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{k+1} - X_k =\sum_{k=1}^{n} [2^k+2] =2n+ 2^{n+1}-2 $$
That is $$a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}= a_{2}-a_1+2n+ 2^{n+1}-2 = 2n+ 2^{n+1}+1 $$

By telescopic once more we remain with 
 $$a_{n+2}= a_2+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left[2k+ 2^{k+1}+1\right]  = 4 +n(n+1) +2^{n+2}-4+n = 2^{n+2}+ n(n+2)$$
Finally $$\color{red}{a_n =  2^{n}+ n(n-2)}$$

also see this [Solving the recurrence $a_{n+1}-2a_n=2^n; a_0 = 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2574485/solving-the-recurrence-a-n1-2a-n-2n-a-0-1/2574509#2574509)

Comment: What should I provide as an answer? $a_{n+1}$?

Comment: You should provide the answer "$a_n = \text{some expression in terms of $n$ only, not in terms of other $a_m$, and without any summation symbols}$". Sorry about the formatting of this; I assumed MathJax would be sensible about breaking spaces.

Comment: @sswwqqaa I hope it is ok now I did all for you